# How do you handle a postback from the messenger persistent menu in the MS Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger

How do you handle a postback from the messenger persistent menu in the MS Bot Framework?

I have not been able to see any channel data.

Please can someone tell me how this event is handled.

Comment: What happened ?

Comment: It seems there is a bug with the persistent menu. Facebook has been notified

Comment: Did they fix it ?

Comment: HI Bob. They say it was recently repaired. Lets hope its smooth sailing from here,

Answer (score 0):

When you click persistent menu you get something like this :

```
{
  "sender":{
    "id":"USER_ID"
  },
  "recipient":{
    "id":"PAGE_ID"
  },
  "timestamp":1458692752478,
  "message":{
    "mid":"mid.1457764197618:41d102a3e1ae206a38",
    "text":"hello, world!",
    "quick_reply": {
      "payload": "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
    }
  }
}
```

[More.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message)

You can get it :

```
string quick_reply = msg.ChannelData != null ? msg.ChannelData.message?.quick_reply?.payload.ToString() : "";
```

I'm using this line of code to get quick reply, but it's the same code for getting callback from persistent menu because it's quick reply actually.

Comment: For some reason, I am not getting any Json back in the channeldata. I am able to handle quick replies usually. I made a model and deserialize it. but i don't get anything at all with the persistent menu.

Comment: What do you have into incoming message ?

Comment: I an unable to see anything, I tried to output the channeldata as a message. but nothing displays. how can I check?

Comment: Download ngrok and make your local address public. Put your generated link as endpoint to your bot framework dashboard. And debug your incoming message.